pod install Xcode Error Failed to save foo.xcodeproj

I've been encountering an issue where, after running pod install, Xcode consistently throws an error: "Failed to save foo.xcodeproj." To clear this warning, I have to click through it more than 50 times.
This has become quite frustrating, as it happens every time I run pod install. Is there a way to prevent this error from occurring?

This issue occurs when Xcode detects external changes while it already has drafted changes.
The most common situations I personally encounter are:

Having multiple instances of Xcode opened on the same project (usually different versions, such as Xcode 15 and Xcode 16).
Applying discard, pull, merge, or other changes in Git outside of Xcode.
Modifying a file using a script, such as with the terminal.

My solution to these issues is as follows:

Keep all the tech stack up to date to the latest stable version (Xcode, macOS)
Ensure only one instance of Xcode is running at a time.
Close Xcode before applying any external changes, and reopen it afterward.
Ensure there is no ongoing process (like a process in terminal or background) when using Xcode.
Always use git as the source of truth for changes (Xcode has wiped out my changes many times, and I don’t trust it anymore).

Hope it helps ( And hope Apple fix these obvious frustrating issues some day :) )
